# Pandas DataFrame - How to make a stacked area graph stack (matplotlib)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, jupyter

I am trying to convert data in a pandas DataFrame in to a stacked area graph but can not seem to get it to stack.

The data is in the format

```
index | datetime (yyyy/mm/dd) | name | weight_change
```

With 6 different people each measured daily.

I want the stacked graph to show the weight_change (y) over the datetime (x) but with weight_change for each of the 6 people stacked on top of each other

The closest I have been able to get to it is with:

```
df = df.groupby['datetime', 'name'], as_index=False).agg({'weight_change': 'sum'})
agg = df.groupby('datetime').sum()
agg.plot.area()
```

This produces the area graph for the aggregate of the weight_change values (sum of each persons weight_change for each day) but I can't figure out how to split this up for each person like the different values here:

[image]

I have tried various things with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your input data. Consider referring to [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of your data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(days=range(4)*2,
                       change=np.random.rand(8)*2.,
                       name=['John',]*4 + ['Jane',]*4))
```

`df`:

```
    change  days    name
0   0.238336    0   John
1   0.293901    1   John
2   0.818119    2   John
3   1.567114    3   John
4   1.295725    0   Jane
5   0.592008    1   Jane
6   0.674388    2   Jane
7   1.763043    3   Jane
```

Now we can simply use `pyplot`'s `stackplot`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

days = df.days[df.name == 'John']
plt.stackplot(days, df.change[df.name == 'John'],
              df.change[df.name == 'Jane'])
```

This produces the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. When I try to create graph I now get ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly. I believe this is referring to the fact the length of data varies for weight column for each person. How would you alter the length of each of these so they match?

Comment: Actually I have artificially made the same using .head but now have TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' nit supported for input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to casting rule 'safe''. I'll Google some now but any ideas to get around this appreciated.

Comment: `stackplot` only works if all `y` data has the same length (and the same `x` values). If that's not the case, you need to tweak your data first. In your original question, you claimed that every person was measured every day, so I didn't assume you had gaps in your data...